# Google Map API V3. Unable to create custom polyline for TRANSIT directions

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am unable to create custom polyline for transit directions on Google API. Only part of the route is rendered, not all. It works for driving, walking & cycling but not for transit. Not sure what exactly am I missing. If someone has faced the same issue, please help!
I have made an example in fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/srs/vF2e9/1/

Sample Code

```
var directionsDisplay, map;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

  function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523)
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    calcRoute();
  }

  function calcRoute() {
    var start = "98012";
    var end = "98014";
    var request = {
      origin: start,
      destination: end,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        var polyLine = new google.maps.Polyline({
            strokeColor: '#FF0000'
          });
        var options = {};
        options.directions = response;
        options.map = map;
        options.polylineOptions = polyLine;
        //options.suppressMarkers = true;
        directionsDisplay.setOptions(options);// = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(options);
        polyLine.setMap(map);
        //directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A polylineOptions anonymous object is not (and shouldn't be) a google.maps.Polyline.

```
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    var polyLineOptions = {
        strokeColor: '#FF0000'
      };
    var options = {};
    options.directions = response;
    options.map = map;
    options.polylineOptions = polyLineOptions;
    //options.suppressMarkers = true;
    directionsDisplay.setOptions(options);// = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(options);
    polyLine.setMap(map);
    //directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
  }
});
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2dBXb/)