# Google Maps Waypoints not showing whole path

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am drawing a simple route from a source to destination using Google Maps V3 Directions Service.

I need to add some locations(midpoints or waypoints) that the route has to pass through. Google maps provides waypoints for this.

I have referred to their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints) and example to add waypoints. But when I try to draw the route by adding waypoints the route is displayed only from the **last location** added in the waypoints array to the **destination**. I want the route displayed from **src** to **destination** with waypoints included along the route.

I have attached my code. Where am I going wrong?

```
        var map;
        var wyPts = [];



    function addWayPoints(location)
    {           
        wyPts.push({
            location:location,
            stopover:true
            });
    }

    function createInfoWindowContent(latLng, contentStr) {
        var content = '<p><b>' + contentStr + ' </b> </p>' + 'LatLng: ' + latLng    ;
        return content;
    }


    function displayRoute(origin, destination, service, display) {
        service.route({
            origin : origin,
            destination : destination,
            //waypoints: [{location: new google.maps.LatLng(30.439025, -97.685654)}, {location: new google.maps.LatLng(30.434882, -97.677015)} , {location:new google.maps.LatLng(30.429495, -97.675274)}],
            waypoints:wyPts,
            optimizeWaypoints: true,
            travelMode : google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING       
        }, function(response, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                display.setDirections(response);
            } else {
                alert('Could not display directions due to: ' + status);

            }
        });
    }


    function initMap() {


        //////////source  destination and middle waypoints

        var src = new google.maps.LatLng(30.444719, -97.686202); // //school
            //addWayPoints(src);
        var midPt1 = new google.maps.LatLng(30.439025, -97.685654); // 
            addWayPoints(midPt1);
        var midPt2 = new google.maps.LatLng(30.434882, -97.677015); // 
            addWayPoints(midPt2);
        var midPt3 = new google.maps.LatLng(30.429495, -97.675274); // 
            addWayPoints(midPt3);


            /* for (var i = 0; i < wyPts.length; i++) {
                alert("pts are : " + wyPts[i].location);
            } */

        var destination = new google.maps.LatLng(30.401820, -97.669545); //


        ///////////draw the map
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center : src,
            mapTypeControlOptions : {
                style : google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
                position : google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT,
                mapTypeIds : [ google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                        google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
                        google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID ]
            },
            zoomControl : true,
            zoomControlOptions : {
                position : google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
            },
            zoom : 14
        });

        //draw infowindow at src and destination
         var coordInfoWindowSrc = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: createInfoWindowContent(src , "Source"),
            maxWidth : 180
        });
        coordInfoWindowSrc.setPosition(src);
        coordInfoWindowSrc.open(map);

         var coordInfoWindowDest = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: createInfoWindowContent(destination , "Destination"),
            maxWidth : 180
        });
        coordInfoWindowDest.setPosition(destination);
        coordInfoWindowDest.open(map);


        //display route
        var polylineProps = new google.maps.Polyline({
            strokeColor : '#009933',
            strokeOpacity : 1.0,
            strokeWeight : 3

        });


        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
            draggable : false, //do not make the route draggable
            map : map,
            suppressMarkers: true ,
            polylineOptions : polylineProps
        });

        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

        displayRoute(src, destination, directionsService,directionsDisplay);

        //add listener to map
        directionsDisplay.addListener(
                'change',
                function() {
                    displayRoute(src, destination, directionsService,
                            directionsDisplay);
                });


    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A polylineOptions anonymous object is not (and shouldn't be) a google.maps.Polyline.

```
var polylineProps = new google.maps.Polyline({
        strokeColor : '#009933',
        strokeOpacity : 1.0,
        strokeWeight : 3

    });
```

Should be:

```
var polylineProps = {
        strokeColor : '#009933',
        strokeOpacity : 1.0,
        strokeWeight : 3

    };
```

If I fix that that, the line appears for the complete route:

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/pw5qokoo/5/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var wyPts = [];



function addWayPoints(location) {
  wyPts.push({
    location: location,
    stopover: true
  });
}

function createInfoWindowContent(latLng, contentStr) {
  var content = '<p><b>' + contentStr + ' </b> </p>' + 'LatLng: ' + latLng;
  return content;
}


function displayRoute(origin, destination, service, display) {
  service.route({
    origin: origin,
    destination: destination,
    //waypoints: [{location: new google.maps.LatLng(30.439025, -97.685654)}, {location: new google.maps.LatLng(30.434882, -97.677015)} , {location:new google.maps.LatLng(30.429495, -97.675274)}],
    waypoints: wyPts,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      display.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      alert('Could not display directions due to: ' + status);

    }
  });
}


function initMap() {


  //////////source  destination and middle waypoints

  var src = new google.maps.LatLng(30.444719, -97.686202); // //school
  //addWayPoints(src);
  var midPt1 = new google.maps.LatLng(30.439025, -97.685654); // 
  addWayPoints(midPt1);
  var midPt2 = new google.maps.LatLng(30.434882, -97.677015); // 
  addWayPoints(midPt2);
  var midPt3 = new google.maps.LatLng(30.429495, -97.675274); // 
  addWayPoints(midPt3);


  /* for (var i = 0; i < wyPts.length; i++) {
              alert("pts are : " + wyPts[i].location);
          } */

  var destination = new google.maps.LatLng(30.401820, -97.669545); //


  ///////////draw the map
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: src,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT,
      mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
        google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
      ]
    },
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
    },
    zoom: 14
  });

  //draw infowindow at src and destination
  var coordInfoWindowSrc = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: createInfoWindowContent(src, "Source"),
    maxWidth: 180
  });
  coordInfoWindowSrc.setPosition(src);
  coordInfoWindowSrc.open(map);

  var coordInfoWindowDest = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: createInfoWindowContent(destination, "Destination"),
    maxWidth: 180
  });
  coordInfoWindowDest.setPosition(destination);
  coordInfoWindowDest.open(map);


  //display route
  var polylineProps = {
    strokeColor: '#009933',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 3

  };


  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    draggable: false, //do not make the route draggable
    map: map,
    suppressMarkers: true,
    polylineOptions: polylineProps
  });

  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

  displayRoute(src, destination, directionsService, directionsDisplay);

  //add listener to map
  directionsDisplay.addListener(
    'change',

    function() {
      displayRoute(src, destination, directionsService,
        directionsDisplay);
    });


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

related question: [Google Map API V3. Unable to create custom polyline for TRANSIT directions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669654/google-map-api-v3-unable-to-create-custom-polyline-for-transit-directions)